# Alexa Skill Configurable Settings Possible?

Tags: echo, settings, alexa-skills-kit

I am making a skill which requires a string parameter that i set by the user. I know it is possible by letting the user say the string - however this is not preferable due to the nature of this string being for usernames - so it wouldn't be very suitable.

So basically is there a way to have the user manually enter in a string into a configurable setting section on a skill?

If not... any idea why Amazon wouldn't want this ability to be there??

Thank you!!!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you can go with account linking process if the user input string is going to be constant, take input from the user and make it a part OAuth token.

Comment: Yeah was thinking of something like that. So just host a simple login screen that returns a token and the string they entered - and ill be able to save that string for the skill then? Thank you

Comment: yes that can be one of the approach you can take :)

Comment: think I will, seems like the simplest approach, cheers.

Comment: So I've made a web page that allows a user to sign in via. Amazon - in which an OAuth token is returned to my client page where I then ask for the string they enter in. This is as far as I've got. Soooo on confirmation of their string, I presume I will need to tie it to the account linking with an Alexa Skill, and somehow attach the string to the payload that contains the access token. My question now I guess is - Is this going to be cool with Amazon, as I haven't seen an example anywhere of people doing this? THANK YOU!!!

Comment: As per my experience with Amazon development team and my alexa development i don't see any problem in this implementation, as similar approach we have taken to get some client information

Comment: Nice one good to know. Appreciate all your advice and help!

Comment: Hi again, I've got as far as hosting my custom page. You can see it here - https://alexacustomloginrl.azurewebsites.net/home . I am now in the process of the account linking on the alexa skill configuration side - but I'm having an issue at the last hurdle. So you can actually try the link above and you'll see what i mean but basically on redirecting back to my alexa skills implicit grant url to finish, I get the error:  
Unable to link your Skill.

Please try again later.

So not sure what I'm doing wrong but the redirect url I send back has all the req. stuff and amazons access token

Comment: @user398707 hey any chance you can help me atm with my situation mentioned in previous comment?

Comment: I think the state is not getting correct value. Can you let me know how you're triggering the launch of webpage

Comment: I'm not actually setting a state value on logging into amazon. So when we come back and then 'complete' the process that goes back to the skill - a hard coded string is just passed over as the state - 'xyz'. When you say triggering the launch of the webpage, there's two - the initial amazon login one and the alexa skill. The amazon login is done using an angular package used for grabbing auth tokens. and the second skill one is simply a redirect using window.location.href="MY_URL+PARAMS" hope thats what you wanted to know?